# How to avoid nested subscribe when working with mixed Maybe and Single

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have come a cross the following requirement:

I have a method that returns `Maybe` and I need to process it in a away that if it returns something then Invoke another method that returns `Single`, otherwise on the `OnComplete` invoke `Single`.

Here is an Snippet:

```
 doSomethingThatReturnsMaybe()
 .flatMapSingleElement(obj-> {
     return doSomethingThatReturnsSingle();
 })
 .subscribe(obj -> LOG.info(obj),
  err -> LOG.err("", err),
  () -> {
     doSomethingThatReturnsSingle()
     .subscribe();
  });
```

Any idea how to get rid of the nested `subscribe` ?

**UPDATE:**
Latest Code Snippet

```
doSomethingThatReturnsMaybe()
  .flatMapSingleElement(obj-> {
    return doSomethingThatReturnsSingle();
  })
  .switchIfEmpty(doSomethingElseThatReturnsSingle())
  .subscribe(obj -> LOG.info(obj),
         err -> LOG.err("", err);
```

Comment: Why can't you use `flatMapSingleElement` like you're doing?

Comment: It is good, but I can't seem to get rid of the nested 'subscribe' because if the maybe emits 'Empty' then I need to call a Single.

Comment: The easiest for me is to change the method that returns 'Maybe' in to 'Single<Optional>' so then I can chain flatMaps all the way with a single 'subscribe' point, but that beats the purpose of having a 'Maybe'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the discussion on the comments, I feel like this could be a solution.

I'd use [switchIfEmpty](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html#switchIfEmpty-io.reactivex.SingleSource-) here.

Something like:

```
doSomethingThatReturnsMaybe()
  .flatMapSingleElement(obj-> {
    return doSomethingThatReturnsSingle();
  })
  .switchIfEmpty(doSomethingThatReturnsSingle())
  .subscribe(obj -> LOG.info(obj),
             err -> LOG.err("", err);
```

`switchIfEmpty` will execute if the `Maybe` returns empty. Note, this is different than what you had. What you had executes `doSomethingThatReturnsSingle()` twice. This new example executes it once. If the maybe returns empty the `switchIfEmpty` will run it once, otherwise, it runs on the `flatMapSingleElement`. Before it was also running once the stream completed.

Comment: Looks like the perfect solution for my case! Thank you so much :-)

Comment: Has anyone encounter a situation where `switchIfEmpty` is called although the `Maybe` is NOT empty?? like it skips the `flatMapSingleElement`.

Comment: Note that doSomethingThatReturnsSingle will always be called,  but the Single that it returns may or may not be subscribed to, depending on the stream.

Comment: indeed. If you want to avoid that, I'd recommend looking into `defer` so you defer the execution of the method `doSomethingThatReturnsSingle`.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding it correctly, then in both the cases(whether Maybe is empty or not), you wanna call the `doSomethingThatReturnsSingle()`. If it is so, below code might help,

```
doSomethingThatReturnsMaybe().isEmpty()
                             .flatMap(isEmpty-> doSomethingThatReturnsSingle())
                             .subscribe(obj-> System.out.println(obj));
```

Comment: unfortunately, I a bit misled you guys, 'doSomethingThatReturnsSingle` is actually 2 different methods that each returns a `Single`. I fixed the code snippet accordingly, so I guess my question would be how can it be that 'doSomethingThatReturnsMaybe' returns an objecy and still `doSomethingElseThatReturnsSingle` gets called instead of `doSomethingThatReturnsSingle` ??